# php headers doesn't downloads

Tags: php, force-download

I was trying to make a "Force Download" via PHP, but all I get are strange symbols.

I tried to add the header ("application/typeofmyfile") and the header ("Content-Disposition")... and many others from many other post from here, but nothing

I've got this:

```
$f_location = "path/myfile.nl2pkg";
$f_name = "myfile.nl2pkg";


header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$f_name); //Here also tried basename($f_name) but nothing
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($f_location));    
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

I'm doing it like this because when an user clicks on the "download" button, with ajax I send him to the page to force the download, put some data in the db and then refresh the main page.

It's my first time working on headers, and for I what read, don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Your code should work in a clean page.. try to run you ajax, do what you have to do, and then open a new empty page with that code and it should work.

Comment: Use header_sent to check weather or not your headers where already send http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

Comment: Ok, for trying it, I added a new tab in the browser and put in all the variables in the header and download worked. Going to do what you ask me, and I will tell you. Gonna check that page also, thanks.

Comment: Exactly as @rennyrocha suggests. You can't download a file through an AJAX request. You have to make a normal request to the server. When you return the headers you used here the user will see a download-box and they will stay on the original page.

Comment: Hi, with Ajax I only pass to a page the variables to force the download (and id from a file and a user to add it to the db), and with thouse variables get the file. As rennyrocha said me, I've done the ajax and then open a new link with location.href and worked fine. Also will check what headers were sending before. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Headers Code seems fine. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

To debug your Code use [headers_sent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) to determine if headers already have been sent. You can also use [headers_list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) to see what headers have already been sent.

```
if (headers_sent()) {
  var_dump(headers_list());
  die('Headers have already been sent');
  exit;
}
```

If you use this right before you define the headers you will probably find the source of your problem.

Comment: Hi, I've done that before sending the headers, and the only one that shows me is the "Powered By PhP" header. As I said, first time working on them. Tried also to do a header_remove() but nothing, so I decided to make it as renny told me, make a page for the ajax to add to the db and another one for redirecting after ajax to the download. I would like to make it in the first page, but well, this works for the moment

Comment: if you see the `Powered By PhP` header, that means your headers have been sent. Try searching for `?> <?php` and similar problems. IT seems you do output something, even if that is just some whitespace. `header_remove` will not do the job if you also already did output some content.

Comment: Thanks, maybe a function I got that return true or false can cause the problems?

Comment: if that true or false is echoed.